# Save Outlook attachments after creating folder in local directory

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to access the sub folder by name "MacroEnabled" in Inbox, find all the attachments in it and save them to local drive.

I use this code to create a folder by name "Documents" and save the attachments. However while doing the second iteration it says file already exist error "58".

```vb
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim olFolder_Inbox As Folder
    Dim olMail As MailItem
    Dim olAttachment As Attachment
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim File_Saved As String
    
    'email service type
    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder_Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("MacroEnabled")

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FolderPath = "Documents"
    For Each olMail In olFolder_Inbox.Items

        If TypeName(olMail) = "MailItem" And olMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
            fso.CreateFolder ("Documents")
            
            For Each olAttachment In olMail.Attachments
            
                olAttachment.SaveAsFile fso.BuildPath(FolderPath, olAttachment.FileName)
                
            Next olAttachment

        End If
    
    Next olMail

    Set ns = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like your code continually tries to recreate the `Documents` folder? So you probably need to first check if it exists, at least assume it does after the first time you create it.

Comment: And you can use the [FolderExists method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/folderexists-method) to do that check.

Comment: Same thing applies to the attachments if two share the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `FolderPath` should present whole path eg. `FolderPath = "C:\Documents"`
If you need you can use relative path for example `FolderPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Documents"`
Then you can use FolderExisits method in loop by adding following instruction:

```
If Not fso.FolderExists(FolderPath) Then fso.CreateFolder (FolderPath )
```

Answer (score 0):

`For Each olMail In olFolder_Inbox.Items
fso.CreateFolder ("Documents_path")`

look at this and try to check if folder Documents exists before creating another

Comment: you have the knowledge to write that code and not knowing why it's creating many folders which is in a loop, that's weird :) Add: `If(Not System.IO.Directory.Exists([the_documents_path])) Then`

Comment: Best of luck then :)